# How to provide thread execution in sequence

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

I would like to ask you whether it's good implementation, and how can I provide that AWSConfigurator will be initialized first, and then provide access to Startup ? While debugging, I can see that `GetParameterRequest` it's an operation which sends request and receive response from server and this operation provides connectionString to db, but before connectionString is returned, debugger jumps into Startup and logger returns empty ConnectionString.

Code of Program.cs

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        public static IHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(async (hostbuilder, builder) =>
                {
                    var configuration = await AWSConfigurator.ConfigureBuilderAsync(builder);
                    builder.AddConfiguration(configuration);
                });
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            });
        }
    }
```

Part of code of AWSConfigurator

```
 var request = new GetParameterRequest()
            {
                Name = $"/development/MYAPP/ConnectionString"
            };
```

I tried to find answer in docs but no result.

I found the solution. If somebody will have same issue in future here's example.

```
return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(async (hostbuilder, builder) =>
                {
                    var configuration = await AWSConfigurator.ConfigureBuilderAsync(builder).Result;
                });
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            });
```

Comment: Where is the connection string being returned in posted code?  The connection string is being used inside the  AWSConfigurator but never being returned to the code posted.

Comment: It is not important where. It is there. I sent a part of configuration which interrupts operation.

Comment: The question is more about .net not AWS. How can I force the entire configuration to be executed before Startup.

Comment: It is.   Your issue is the connection string isn't being returned to the Main method.  The code is working you just aren't seeing the connection string in the logger.

Comment: `ConfigureAppConfiguration` is not designed for `async` functions, so it's not waiting for it to complete. You need to find a way to make that run synchronously. Considering you are in a console app (up until the point you call `.Run()`) you might as well just do `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. Or try find a synchronous function in the SDK `AWSConfigurator.ConfigureBuilder`

Comment: Yes thank you :) I found solution. Solution is `var configuration = await AWSConfigurator.ConfigureBuilderAsync(builder).Result;`, just Result was needed at the end. :)